# addfieldtotab data types in SIlverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

below is theexample from Silverstripe.org for addfieldToTab

```
 $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', DateField::create('Date','Date of article'));   
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextareaField::create('Teaser'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('Author','Author of article'));
```

It show that Text type is TextareaField, varchar is TextField, Date is DateField.

But what about for the other data types, I can find in the documentation for the following,

Boolean
CompositeDBField
Currency
Datetime
Decimal
Double
Enum
Float
ForeignKey
HTMLText
HTMLVarchar
Int
Money
MultiEnum
Percentage
PrimaryKey
Text
Time
Year

Comment: well, the db field type is loosley coupled to the form field type, you can use what fits for your needs. When scaffolding a form it takes a standard field type (can be overwritten), but the question is more vice versa: i have a field type (e.g. email field), what data type should i use for it to save in db?

Answer (score 1):

For a complete list of fields check out the subclasses listed at http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-FormField.html. Field types are often flexible and can support multiple data types or relations, just as particular data types can be often be represented by a variety of form fields. You can create your own field types too by subclassing `FormField`. So it depends on context as to what will be the best fit.